# Refreshing a UICollectionview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, reloaddata

Does anyone know how to reload/refresh a UICollectionView while the collection view is being displayed? Basically I'm looking for something similar to the standard reloadData method for a UITableview.

Comment: Maybe I am misunderstanding, but UICollectionView implements reloadData.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You can just call:

```
[self.myCollectionView reloadData];
```

Individual sections and items can also be reloaded:

```
[self.myCollectionView reloadSections:indexSet];
[self.myCollectionView reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:arrayOfIndexPaths];
```

Comment: WFIW I believe the reason why people are coming across this is because they're used to calling [myTableView reloadData] but with UICollectionViews you must call [myCollectionView.collectionView reloadData].

Comment: [self.myCollectionView reloadData]; call only once.
want to reload all data.

Answer (score 11):

```
[self.collectionView reloadData];
```

Comment: While this will indeed achieve the desired results, using reloadData redraws all the cells and can affect performance.

Comment: Not a good idea, because reloading the full table you get bad perfomance and energy is drawn.

Answer (score 1):

The correct and best way is to use

```
NSMutableArray *indexPaths = [NSMutableArray array];
//prepare some data
//batchupdate as block
[self.collectionView performBatchUpdates:^{
    //operations like delete
   [self.collectionView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:NSMakeRange(1, count)]];
    [self.collectionView insertItemsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths];
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    // call something when ready
    }
}];
```

and all gets precomputed an nicely animated. The best practice is to first remove and than add all elements, to avoid conflicts.